# Need assistance with a simple Pinescript code

Tags: pine-script

I have probably one of the most simple scripts for pine script and for some reason I can only get the "Sell" plot shapes to show up and not the "Buy" plot shapes. I have no idea what could be wrong with this code, please someone help! Here's my script:

````
// © tommyf1001

//@version=4
study(title="EMAs + Stoch RSI", overlay=true, resolution="")


// ---------- Indicators

smoothK = input(3, "K", minval=1, group="Stoch RSI")
smoothD = input(3, "D", minval=1, type=input.integer, group="Stoch RSI")
lengthRSI = input(14, "RSI Length", minval=1, group="Stoch RSI")
lengthStoch = input(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1, group="Stoch RSI")
stoch_low = input(10, title="Stoch Low", group="Stoch RSI")
stoch_high = input(90, title="Stoch High", group="Stoch RSI")

ema_1 = input(21, "EMA Fast", group="EMAs")
ema_2 = input(50, "EMA Slow", group="EMAs")


// ------------- Functions

// --------- Stoch RSI
rsi1 = rsi(close, lengthRSI)
stoch_k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
stoch_d = sma(stoch_k, smoothD)

stoch_rsi_bull = (barssince(stoch_k < stoch_low) <= 10 and crossover(stoch_k, stoch_low))
stoch_rsi_bear = (barssince(stoch_k > stoch_high) <= 10 and crossunder(stoch_k, stoch_high))


// --------- EMAs

ema_bull = (ema_1 > ema_2)
ema_bear = (ema_1 < ema_2)

bull = (ema_bull and stoch_rsi_bull)
bear = (ema_bear and stoch_rsi_bear)


// -----------------------------------------------------------
// Plots

plotshape(bull ? close : na, title='Buy', style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text='Buy', size=size.small)
plotshape(bear ? close : na, title='Sell', style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text='Sell', size=size.small)```
````

Answer (score 0):

**(ema_1 > ema_2) condition is wrong you should change it (ema_1 < ema_2) **

Comment: No that can’t be it because ema_1 < ema_2 would mean the 21 EMA is below the 50 EMA which would be the bear condition, which is working and properly displaying the sell plot shape. I’m trying to show BUY signal plot shape when 21 EMA IS ABOVE 50 EMA, which would be written as ema_1 > ema_2

Answer (score 0):

I think this is as expected, there is inverse correlation between ema_bull and ema_bear. If ema_bull is true then ema_bear should be false, and vice versa. If (ema_1 > ema_2) is true then (ema_1 < ema_2) is false. That is why plotshape only plot one of those two.

Comment: Except when you change time frames and the 21 EMA is clearly above 50 EMA and there is the stoch RSI crossover, I SHOULD see buy signals appear but I do not. Try adding this to a chart to see for yourself, it will not show a buy signal even when the condition is true

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong with my script. I forgot to define ema(source, length) before using it in the function. I was referencing the input only which was just an integer. Surprised nobody else spotted this mistake, but I wanted to make sure I posted in here that I figured it out in case anyone else makes this mistake!